# How to merge two JSON files into one

Tags: php, json

I have two json files named: users.json and users_custom.json which I created from mysql database using php. users.json file looks like:

```
[{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "Name" : "Mr. A",
    "phone" : "12345"
},
{
    "user_id" : "2",
    "Name" : "Mr. B",
    "phone" : "23456"
}]
```

and users_custom.json file looks like:

```
[{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "Name" : "Mr. A Modified",
    "email" : "someone@gmail.com"
},
{
    "user_id" : "2",
    "Name" : "Mr. B",
    "address" : "some address"
}]
```

so, in users_custom.json file I have modified some fields and also added some new fields. Now, I want to merge users_custom.json over users.json file into users_final.json file. At the end users_final file should looks like this:

```
[{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "Name" : "Mr. A Modified",
    "phone" : "12345"
    "email" : "someone@gmail.com"
},
{
    "user_id" : "2",
    "Name" : "Mr. B",
    "phone" : "23456"
    "address" : "some address"
}]
```

At the end I will import the users_final.json file to MongoDB database. Any idea or example code will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using?  Have you tried the most straightforward approach of deserializing these JSON representations into usable arrays, merging the arrays as desired, and then serializing back to JSON?

Comment: I am using php. I have tried using php array_merge function. It does not really help me because my file will contain approximately half million records and php does not deal good with large size of array. I need something like awk or sed for json file

Comment: Or, I dunno, cut the task into manageable sizes?

Comment: If your concern is over not having resources to marshall both arrays in memory, then perhaps you need to take the approach of using a streaming JSON parser such that you can read data only a portion of the data structure into memory at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward, get contents of both files, decode them both, loop them accordingly, if the user id's match, merge them, after that process is complete, encode the resultant, then write the file. Example:

```
// $contents_of_users = file_get_contents('users.json');
$contents_of_users = '[{ "user_id" : "1", "Name" : "Mr. A", "phone" : "12345"},{ "user_id" : "2", "Name" : "Mr. B", "phone" : "23456"}]';
// $contents_of_users_custom = file_get_contents('users_custom.json');
$contents_of_users_custom = '[{ "user_id" : "1", "Name" : "Mr. A Modified", "email" : "someone@gmail.com"},{ "user_id" : "2", "Name" : "Mr. B", "address" : "some address"}]';

$data_user = json_decode($contents_of_users, true);
$data_user_custom = json_decode($contents_of_users_custom, true);
$final = $data_user;
foreach($final as $key => &$user) {
    foreach($data_user_custom as $user_custom) {
        if($user['user_id'] == $user_custom['user_id']) {
            $user = array_merge($user, $user_custom);
        }
    }
}

$final = json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);

file_put_contents('users_final.json', $final);
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SYKSPS)